# Pycharm printing unwanted stuff

Tags: python, pycharm, output

Can't find anything similar anywhere, so i though about asking here, hope it is appropriate.

Im running a simple script on Pycharm, so that the Run tab opens. On the select Run/Debug Configuration i chose the option to run the script with the Python console, so that the variables window pops up. But when i execute some code, it prints a lot of stuff that i dont want after the true output, like shown in the image.

[image]

How do i get rid of that?

Comment: What do you see if you unselect the "run with python console" option?

Comment: It won't show up that stuff, just the output as I wanted, but then the variables window won't pop up

Comment: That's the way "Run in Python console" works. If you want to view the values of variables, you can set a breakpoint and run with the debugger instead.

Comment: Yeah I guess it is just like that. Oh well, thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

The extra output you see is because you are running the script with the Python console. You should deselect this option in your Run Configuration. If you ever need to inspect values of variables, then you should run your script by clicking the Debug button instead of the Run button. This will run in a different Debug window which has a pane to inspect variables.